# Physical location of codes on SVN repository

Tags: svn

I installed TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN server for implementing version control in my project. I successfully implemented installation on Server A and Successfully using repository project on workstation A including SVN commands(checkout , update , edit conflicts etc..).

Here my problem is that, I am releasing the code from Server A. So in repository folder I am not finding the actual repository version code location. Actually in server where actually the repository code resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server hosts your SVN repositories. Most likely, they are in `C:\Repositories`. Read the [VisualSVN Server Getting Started](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) guide.